# Getting No virtual method getSavedStateRegistry() in Android when calling MethodChannel in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-method-channel

I am developing  an app in flutter . I am trying to call a methodchannel from flutter to Android

When the `var accountToken=await platform.invokeMethod("ccAvenuePayment", {"params": jsonEncode(payment.toJson())});`

I am getting a crash in the log and app closes

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getSavedStateRegistry()Landroidx/savedstate/SavedStateRegistry; in class Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity' appears in /data/app/~~kpJG3PwxxqPGEm-YvsB4dA==/ae.ehail.rider_ios2-wdmI__mnIKJeTtbATI_naw==/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.initDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at mumbai.dev.testapp.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(29070):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process (29070): Sending signal. PID: 29070 SIG: 9
```

I can't figure out the issue . The method channel not called at all .

I searched the internet but can find this error `No virtual method getSavedStateRegistry()`

This is my code

https://gist.github.com/RageshAntony/93f77677cb69720616254fc710dd7832

Please help me

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @awaistoor I think I replaced AppCompactActivity  with Activity

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `app/build.gradle` had a configuration set to use an older version of `androidx.fragment:fragment` (1.0.0), and `SavedStateRegistry` was added in 1.4.0. I'm revisiting an old project so I'm guessing a newer version of flutter requires this newer version of androidx.fragment.

```
allprojects {
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0" //deleteMe
```

I removed that line to resolve this issue.